# Center an element with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to center an element. The element may change width, therefore I cannot use the CSS method of `margin: 0 auto`.

Here is my code:

```
$.fn.center = function() {
    $(this).css({
        'margin-left': ($(this).parent().innerWidth() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2  + "px",
        'margin-right': ($(this).parent().innerWidth() - $(this).outerWidth()) + ($(this).outerWidth() / 2)  + "px"
    });   
};
$('#nav').center();
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working. Can you help me figure out why? Should I be using absolute positioning?

Thanks.

Comment: Show a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo maybe?

Comment: _this isn't working_ means what?

Comment: @davidthomas its live on a tumblr site im making: http://dev-indiehaz.tumblr.com/ should be centering the navigation links under the title!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for all this..

since you are making the sub-elements (the `li`) to be inline-block, just set the container `#nav` to have `text-align:center`.

and do not set any margins at all..

Answer (score 1):

You can position your element `position:absolute;` and then, using your formula to set the left position. Other way is position the element `position:relative;`, and use the `outerWidth` to set the width of the element and then position it with `margin:0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

It may works :

```
var space = ($(this).parent().width() - $(this).width) / 2;

$(this).css({marginLeft : space , marginRight : space});
```

Answer (score 0):

To centre a canvas element with an id of 'gameCanvas', contained within a div with an id of 'game' I recently used:

```
$('#gameCanvas').css('margin-left', ($('#game').width() - $('#gameCanvas').width()) / 2);
```

So if you know your containers id, replace '#gameCanvas' with `this` and '#game' with your containers ID